# Convergence of random variables, almost sure and L1

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Let $Y_1, Y_2, ...$ be a sequence of random variables such that $Y_n \rightarrow 1 \ \text{a.s.}$ and $\mathbb{E}[Y_n] \rightarrow 1 \ \text{as} \ n \rightarrow \infty.$ I want to prove or disprove the following statement: $\mathbb{E}[|Y_n - 1|] \rightarrow 0 \ \text{as} \ n \rightarrow \infty.$

I think this statement is true. I know that since $\mathbb{E}[Y_n] \rightarrow 1$, there exists some $C \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $\mathbb{E}[Y_n] < C$ and thus $\mathbb{E}[|Y_n|]$ is bounded, which means that $\mathbb{E}[|Y_n - 1|]$ is bounded. Assume that $\mathbb{E}[|Y_n - 1|]$ is bounded by some constant $D \in \mathbb{R}.$ Let $\epsilon > 0.$ Then,
$$\mathbb{E}[|Y_n - 1|] = \mathbb{E}[|Y_n - 1| \mathbf{1}_{|Y_n - 1| \geq \epsilon}] + \mathbb{E}[|Y_n - 1| \mathbf{1}_{|Y_n - 1| < \epsilon}].$$
Thus,
$$\mathbb{E}[|Y_n - 1|] \leq D P(|Y_n - 1| > \epsilon) + \epsilon.$$
The right hand side goes to $0.$
However, I am not sure that this works. I feel like the bounded thing I did in the beginning isn't totally valid. Can someone help me? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $\mathbb E[Y_n]<C$ then you cannot deduce that $\mathbb E[\vert Y_n\vert]$ is bounded so your proof is invalid.

In fact you can find a counterexample: $Y_n=1$ with probabiliy $1-\frac{2}{n^2}$, $Y_n=1+n^2$ with probability $\frac{1}{n^2}$ and $Y_n=1-n^2$ with probability $\frac{1}{n^2}$. For all $\varepsilon>0$, Borel-Cantelli's lemma yields that for $n$ large enough, $\vert Y_n-1\vert<\varepsilon$, hence $Y_n\to1$ almost surely. Moreover $\mathbb E[Y_n]=1\to1$. But $\mathbb E[\vert Y_n-1\vert]=2\not\to0$.

Note that if in your initial statement you had assumed that $\mathbb E[\vert Y_n\vert]\to1$ then you would have been able to conclude positively. That is a direct application of Scheffe's lemma https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scheff%C3%A9%27s_lemma.